# php artisan route:list RuntimeException Session store not set on request

Tags: laravel, session, routes, laravel-artisan

When I check the route list by command form doc:

```
php artisan route:list //RuntimeException:  Session store not set on request.
```

I found it should be better use helper function `session()` instead of `$request->session()` in `Controller __contract` function.

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        //use $request->session()->has($var) will occur the exception as this post said.
        if (session()->has($var)) {          
        //do something;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Formatted in-line content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `session()` instead `$request->session()` in *controller*, like:

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        //use $request->session()->has($var) will occur the exception as this post said.
        if (session()->has($var)) {          
        //do something;
        }
    }
}
```